# WPToolkit not appear in the references after successful install

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, nuget, wptoolkit

I installed the WPToolkit through NuGet and it was successful, but it wasn't add into project's solutions, that's why i can't add in the xaml

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox...
```

*The name "AutoCompleteBox" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit".
*

So what can i do?

I am using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641
```

Thx,
Robertoq

Comment: Are you really asking how to add a reference to your project?

Comment: Yes, because i'm new in wp :( Everywhere i found that install and use it, there wasn't another step. I tried add dll manually but not worked. So what are the steps? which dll (wp8.1), how, etc... Thx

Comment: If you have the assembly file (dll), the please read the [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Reference Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh708954(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for instructions.

Comment: after install the WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16 folder created in the project's packages folder. I added into references the

Comment: So in the *Solution Explorer* in Visual Studio, if you open the *References* folder of the relevant project, can you see an entry for your `WPToolkit` dll? Does it have a yellow error icon?

Comment: after install the WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16 folder created in the project's packages folder. I added into references the 
"<project>packages\WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16\lib\wp8\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll" file and it's appeared in the references list. When i open it in the object browser than i see the AutoCompleteBox and the others, but the problem not solved, i got error message "The name "AutoCompleteBox" does not exist". Why?

Here is screenshot:
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140612/Clipboard01_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Comment: Have you Cleaned and Rebuilt your project yet?

Comment: yes, but not helped :(  I downloaded a sample app which is working, but there was some items on Reference Manager / Assemblies / Extensions, see image:
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140612/Clipboard02_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

How can i add items there and what ?
(The Assemblies tab lists all .NET Framework assemblies that are available for referencing.)

Comment: You don't add references there. You use the Browse option to browse to the folder containing the dll.

Comment: But if i browse and add dll than it will be appear the Browse / Recent page, not Assemblies. Otherwise now i get this error (Error 1 Cannot find type System.Windows.Controls.Control in module System.Windows.dll) if i checked the Toolkit chekcbox under Reference manager. BUT, how can i set the toolkit, what is the problem??? :(

Comment: With all due respect to you, while I have tried to help you, your complete lack of programming knowledge pretty much excludes you from using this website. In order to use this website, you need to have some basic development knowledge. As it is clear that you have none, I am now voting to close this question as being ['Off Topic'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Robertoq, currently `WPToolkit` doesn't support new `Windows Phone 8.1 XAML` (i.e. the new framework targeting Universal Application API's) based application.

But they do support `Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Application`, which uses the old `8.0 Silverlight API's` for application framework. And that you can find [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit/4.2013.8.16) & [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/). I tested this myself, I added the toolkit to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application & it worked.

So you don't need to waste your time in adding .dll to a project where it doesn't support that .dll. If you want to build a 8.1 application & you do need to use the toolkit then just target 8.1 Silverlight app.

You can create one by going to `Visual Studio 2013 -> New Project -> Universal App -> Windows Phone App -> Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight) -> Windows Phone 8.1 (Select)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. Thank you