# Dropdownlist with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: drop-down-menu, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, wptoolkit

I want to create a simple Dropdownlist with for a WP8.1 app. I can't use the Listpicker from the WP Toolkit because it doesn't support WP 8.1 xaml as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308632/how-to-use-windows-phone-toolkit-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181903/wptoolkit-not-appear-in-the-references-after-successful-install).
I don't want to create a Universal App. Is there really no possible way to create a Dropdown List?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use a `ComboPicker` instead, if you're running WP 8.1 runtime.

Here's a quick migrating guide: [Migrating from the Windows Phone Toolkit ListPicker to the new XAML ComboBox (Display a ListPicker in XAML apps)](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/05/22/Migrating-from-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ListPicker-to-the-new-XAML-ComboBox-%28Display-a-ListPicker-in-XAML-apps%29.aspx)

---

```XAML
<ComboBox Header="Combo picker" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really becoming desperate about this.